# Python : Revert to base __str__ behavior

Tags: python, string

How can I revert back to the default function that python uses if there is no `__str__` method?

```
class A :
   def __str__(self) :
      return "Something useless"

class B(A) :
   def __str__(self) :
      return some_magic_base_function(self)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `object.__str__()`:

```
class A:
   def __str__(self):
      return "Something useless"

class B(A):
   def __str__(self):
      return object.__str__(self)
```

This gives you the default output for instances of `B`:

```
>>> b = B()
>>> str(b)
'<__main__.B instance at 0x7fb34c4f09e0>'
```

Answer (score 2):

"the default function that python uses if there is no `__str__` method" is `repr`, so:

```
class B(A) :
   def __str__(self) :
      return repr(self)
```

This holds whether `__repr__` has been overridden in the inheritance chain or not. IOW, if you ALSO need to bypass possible overrides of `__repr__` (as opposed to using them if they exist, as this approach would do), you will need explicit calls to `object.__repr__(self)` (or to `object.__str__` as another answer suggested -- same thing).